# Java: Removing a JLayeredPane and adding a ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have set a game menu screen on my JFrame using a layered panel. I want to remove all the components from the JFrame and add a new content panel. I've spent a few hours trying to work through this issue but I am unable to come up with a good solution.

```
public myJFrame ()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize (1030, 727);
    setVisible(true);
    newGame = new JButton();
    loadGame = new JButton();
    quitGame = new JButton();
    newGame.setBounds(new Rectangle(10,600,200,110));
    newGame.setIcon(pic1);
    newGame.setOpaque(false);
    newGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    newGame.setBorderPainted(false);
    loadGame.setBounds(new Rectangle(210,600,200,110));
    loadGame.setIcon(pic2);
    loadGame.setOpaque(false);
    loadGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    loadGame.setBorderPainted(false);
    quitGame.setBounds(new Rectangle(410,600,200,110));
    quitGame.setIcon(pic3);
    quitGame.setOpaque(false);
    quitGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    quitGame.setBorderPainted(false);
    background.setBounds(0,0,1030,727);
    titletext.setBounds(0,0,726,170);
    lp = getLayeredPane();
    lp.add(titletext, new Integer (4)); //* I messed around with these integers quite a bit. *//
    lp.add(newGame, new Integer (20));   //* They don't seem to be logically adding to the panel. *//
    lp.add(loadGame, new Integer(20));  //* I want the background and titletext to appear behind *//
    lp.add(quitGame, new Integer (20));  //* the JButtons. *//
    lp.add(background, new Integer (1));

    newGame.addActionListener(this);
    loadGame.addActionListener(this);
    quitGame.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    Object obj = event.getSource();
    if (obj == newGame)
    {
        System.out.println("New Game");
        lp.remove(4);
        getContentPane().add(mop, "Center");         //* Removes myWelcomePanel mwp and adds myOptionsPanel mop *//                          
        repaint();
        mop.startgame.addActionListener(this);
    }
```

I have tried repainting, revalidating and removing only certain components but nothing seems to work. I would expect the code posted above to remove the titletext image, but it removes the background image instead.

I would prefer not to mess with the second content pane because it contains a number of objects which I have configured previously.

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

[`JLayeredPane.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#remove(int)) refers to the child's absolute index, not its layer position.  Why don't you either remove by reference, or simply set the child component's visibility to hidden?

Comment: The code below and lp.removeAll() clears the JFrame, but I can't seem to get the new panel to display.

`lp.setVisible(false);`<br/> 
`setLayout(newBorderLayout());`  
`getContentPane().add(mop, "Center");`                             
`repaint();`

Comment: Removing each component individually works as well, but I still can't display the new panel and its objects.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to make it work. It seems that I must remove each component individually instead of using removeAll(). I identified a new GridLayout sp and set that as the layout. Finally, I had to use revalidate instead of repaint. Repaint left me with a blank screen. If anyone could comment on what is happening here, I would appreciate it!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    Object obj = event.getSource();
    if (obj == newGame)
    {
        System.out.println("New Game");
        lp.remove(background);
        lp.remove(titletext);
        lp.remove(newGame);
        lp.remove(loadGame);
        lp.remove(quitGame);

        getContentPane().setLayout(sp);
        getContentPane().add(mop, "Center");
        revalidate();
        mop.startgame.addActionListener(this); 
    }
```